the style tag is displayed as text on the page
it's in the file README.md in GitHub.
the  tag is displayed as text on the page in GitHub.
Please tell me where is the error?
I'm a beginner developer.
Thanks for your help))
Еhe code works online on the checkout page HTML
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <titel></titel>
        <style>
           .fig {
            text-align: center; /* Выравнивание по центру */
            font-style: italic; /* Курсивное начертание */
            margin-top: 0; /* Отступ сверху */
            margin-bottom: 0; /* Отступ снизу */
            color: #000000; /* Цвет подрисуночной подписи */
            h1 { font-size: xx-large; }
            h2 { font-size: large; }
            hr {
                border: none; /* Убираем границу */
                background-color: black; /* Цвет линии */
                height: 1px; /* Толщина линии */
                }
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <figure class="fig">
           <img src="https://img.shields.io/badge/git-%23F05033.svg?style=for-the-badge&logo=git&logoColor=white" width="200" height="200">
           <img src="https://img.shields.io/badge/github-%23121011.svg?style=for-the-badge&logo=github&logoColor=white" width="280" height="200">
           <figcaption>
              <h1> Learn GIT & Terminal </h1>
           </figcaption>
           <hr>
           <figcaption>
              <h2> Beginner's Guide to Version Control & Command Line </h2>
           </figcaption>
        </figure>
    <body>
</html>


I'm not sure if I understand the question, are you trying to use this code in your README.md file? In that case, it won't work, as README.md is a markdown file, which works differently than HTML.
